# How to get parent object when context is function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, partial-application

I would like to write curring function for object methods. I want to make this possible:

```js
Function.prototype.curry = function (){
  var originalFunction = this;
  var args = ...; // here goes logic embracing arguments
  var bind = ???; //how to get reference to someObject ???
  return function(){
    return originalFunction.apply(bind, args);
  }
}

var someObject = {
  doSomething : function (param1, param2, param3){
    //do something with params
    return param1 + ' ' + param2 + ' ' + param3;
  }
}

someObject.doSomethingCurried = someObject.doSomething.curry('param1 value', 'param2 value');

//I want to be able to do:
someObject.doSomethingCurried('param3 value')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [some tricks](//stackoverflow.com/a/36031478/4928642), but in fact you should just pass context as a first argument, like native `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here

Function.prototype.curry = function (context,arg){
  var originalFunction = this;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1) ; // here goes logic embracing arguments
  var bind = context; //how to get reference to someObject ???
  return function(){
    return originalFunction.apply(bind, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
  }
}

var someObject = {
  myObj:"Myobj",
  doSomething : function (param1, param2, param3){
    console.log(this);
    //do something with params
    return param1 + ' ' + param2 + ' ' + param3;
  }
}

someObject.doSomethingCurried = someObject.doSomething.curry(someObject,'param1 value', 'param2 value');

//I want to be able to do:
console.log(someObject.doSomethingCurried('param3 value'));
```